# What is a abgedrungene Ausnahme?

Tags: meaning

In Kant's "Grundlegung zur Metaphysik der Sitten", in the second Abschnitt (Chapter) at the end of page 424 there is the word *abgedrungene*. What does it mean?

> Ob nun dieses gleich in unserm eigenen unparteiisch angestellten Urteile nicht gerechtfertiget werden kann, so beweiset es doch, daß wir die[55] Gültigkeit des kategorischen Imperativs wirklich anerkennen, und uns (mit aller Achtung für denselben) nur einige, wie es uns scheint, unerhebliche und uns **abgedrungene** Ausnahmen erlauben.

(I could not find it using duck-duck-go, nor on dict.)

Comment: _"... nor on dict."_ https://www.dwds.de/wb/abdringen Maybe you just used the wrong dictionary. That verb is deprecated though.

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abdringen

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, deprecated by whom? :)  I think you mean obsolete.

Comment: @CarstenS Yes, obsolete was  what I meant.

Comment: The word is hardly obsolete. I'd consider it stylistically better in a lot of cases than "abzwingen" (depends on context, of curse).

Comment: @Polygnome _"The word is hardly obsolete."_  DWDS says it is.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ [Actual data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=abdringen%2Cabgedrungen%2Cabzwingen%2Cabgezwungen&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=3) [looks a bit different](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=31&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&content=zwingt+ab%2Cdringt+ab%2Czwang+ab%2Cdrang+ab&direct_url=t1%3B%2Czwingt%20ab%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdringt%20ab%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Czwang%20ab%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrang%20ab%3B%2Cc0), though.

Comment: @Polygnome The second graph counts occurrences such as *drang ab und zu*, *drang ab Mitte*. The first one seems off too; DWDS-Kernkorpus has 2 hits for forms of [abdringen](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=abdringen&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_asc&limit=10) vs. 62 for forms of [abzwingen](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=abzwingen&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_asc&limit=10)